# C++ pipe to modify input file with multiple programs

Tags: c++, pipe

I've been doing this task for +3 weeks now and I'm sure it's a piece of cake to somebody out there, so I'm just going to ask if somebody could write me some example code with these requirements:

1. Task is in **C++** and the main point is to become familiar with **pipes**
2. It should be called like this (I think) from cmd: `cat inputfile.cpp | ./program01 ./program02`. What I'm trying to say is (I think): *"Do modifications to file inputfile.cpp using programs program01 and program02"*.
3. Using pipes, firstly program01 removes all occurances of something in the inputfile.cpp (for example all empty rows). After all empty rows are removed, program02 should remove all occurances of something else (comments for example).

Does my ask make any sense? I mean, are pipes even meant to be used that way (first run other program then another)?

Can I possibly run multiple files through multiple programs for example like `cat input1.cpp input2.cpp input3.cpp | ./program01 ./program02 ./program03`.

I've written a bunch of programs that does various things to a file, but that is not the main point of the task. The main point is the "piping" part but I really, really just don't get it.

Any guidance is appreciated (some code below).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "programs.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    int result;

    result = pipe(fd);
    if(result < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(2);
    }

    // Child
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            // I guess I should do some piping-magic here?
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    // Parent
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {

        }
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The term pipe refers to the programmatic concept of a pipe, as well as the `|` operator when working on the CLI (both of which are closely related, but not the exact same). The CLI pipe takes the output of the first command and "pipes" it into the second command. This is assuming that the first command outputs something to `stdout` and the second accepts input on `stdin`. If the second program also outputs something, you can continue to pipe that into a third program. So I assume what you want is this: `cat input | program1 | program2`.

Comment: In order to use pipes all you do is read from `std::cin` and write to `std::cout`. You don't need to `fork()` a new process for that.

Comment: In any case, some general SO advice: your question, as is, is somewhat **too broad** (_" if somebody could write me some example code"_). Try reading up on the concepts involved, then narrow down your issue to a very *specific* problem. Then look that up - if you can't find info on it, ask a *specific question* on it. I know that all the info is out there as I've been through the same task (more or less) just a week ago. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing the bash pipe command with the pipes to obtain IPC.
In bash the pipe doesn't pass the arguments, but redirect the stdout of a command to the next command as stdin. So in your c++ program you should read from stdin and write to stdout ([relevant stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538982/piping-and-command-line-arguments)).
You can do something like

```
cat file | ./program1 > file
```

to chain programs

```
cat file | ./program1 | ./program2 > file
```

Comment: I added some code to my original question. Can you please tell me how would I "pass" the standard input to the program01 for modification?
Should I pass it to program01 line by line? What I've understood, the examples show how to combine two strings, not how to modify a file that can have thousands of rows.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your intentions. I think you're confusing the bash pipe command with the pipes to communicate between processes inside a program.

Answer (score 2):

To process data from the shell's pipe all you have to do is read in data from `std::cin` and output the results to `std::cout`. The shell manages the actual pipes.

Here is a program that does nothing. It simple passes the data from the incoming "pipe" to the outgoing "pipe":

Do nothing using "pipes":

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char c;
    while(std::cin.get(c))
        std::cout.put(c);
}
```

A program to remove every blank line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        if(line.empty()) // skip empty lines
            continue;

        // otherwise send them out    
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```